# Access class object from other class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write functions that can reference tkinter objects from classes outside of the one it is written in. My `class Base` code is from a tkinter tutorial from "Sentdex" on Youtube, and the pages below is a simple iteration of his technique.

I would like to be able to reconfigure `ButtonOne` on `PageOne` from `DISABLED` to `NORMAL` after clicking a button on another page, but can't find any working method online.

```html
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Base(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(height=500, width=1500, bg="Red")
        self.Button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 1", state=DISABLED)
        self.Button1.pack()
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.config(height=500, width=1500, bg="Blue")
        self.Button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 2", state=NORMAL)
        self.Button2.pack()

class PageThree(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        menu = tk.Menu(self)
        controller.config(menu=menu)
        self.config(height=500, width=1500, bg="Green")
        menu = tk.Menu(self)
        controller.config(menu=menu)
        subMenu = tk.Menu(self)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Pages", menu=subMenu)
        subMenu.add_command(label="Page One", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        subMenu.add_command(label="Page Two", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        subMenu.add_command(label="Page Three", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        self.Button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 3", state=NORMAL)
        self.Button3.pack()

program = Base()
program.mainloop()
```

When I try something like

```html
self.Button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 3", state=NORMAL, command=self.enableOne)
    self.Button3.pack()

def enableOne(self):
    Base.PageOne.Button1.config(state=NORMAL)
```

I get the error message:

```html
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/R21660/PycharmProjects/Step1/ExampleforStack.py", line 53, in enableOne
    Base.PageOne.Button1.config(state=NORMAL)
AttributeError: type object 'Base' has no attribute 'PageOne'
```

Thanks.

UPDATE:
`self.Button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Button 3", state=NORMAL, command=lambda: PageOne.Button1.config(state=NORMAL))` doesn't work either because "PageOne" has no attribute "Button1."

However, `command=lambda: PageOne.enableOne)` does nothing but doesn't give an error message.

Comment: I believe it is the use of "controller" or "parent" or a lambda command that I am missing, but I can't find any documentation that tells me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PageOne instance is not known by Base class, but is known by Base instances (inside frames list).

Instead of:

```
def enableOne(self):
    Base.PageOne.Button1.config(state=NORMAL)
```

I would try:

```
def enableOne(self):
    self.controller.frames[PageOne].Button1.config(state=NORMAL)
```

provided that you add self.controller=controller in **init** of Page3

Comment: The interpreter says that `parent` is not defined, as though it is a variable name. Am I missing a line of code prior to avoid this?

Comment: self.parent (provided that you add `self.parent=parent` in `__init__` of Page3)

Comment: with the `self.parent` line in addition to your code, I now get the error: `AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'frames'`

Comment: I believe I should not try to debug the code without running it, sorry. A last try with controller ?

Comment: Haha! That did it! Thanks for the help Gelineau; I hope it works in the rest of my project.